# Constructor for subclass says super() is undefined

Tags: java, constructor

I have made this class in java

```
  package mainpackage;

  public class Users {
    public char username;
    public char name;
    public char surname;
    public char department;
    public int usersCounter;

    public char getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(char username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public char getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(char surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public char getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(char name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public char getDepartment() {
        return this.department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(char department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public int getUsersCounter() {
        return this.usersCounter;
    }

    public void setUsersCounter(int usersCounter) {
        this.usersCounter = usersCounter;
    }

    public Users(char userName, char Name, char surName, char Department, int UsersCounter) {
        username = userName;
        name = Name;
        surname= surName;
        department = Department;
        usersCounter = UsersCounter;
    }   

  }
```

and i also made a subclass in which I try to create the constructor of the subclass,but it shows me an error in super(which i put inside the constructor of the subclass) saying that the constructor Users is undefined.I am using Eclipse and the only solution to this problem is to create a constructor Users,but it already exists!!!

```
  package mainpackage;

  public class Students extends Users {

    static int registrationNumber;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public int getNumber() {
        return this.registrationNumber;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void setNumber(char registrationNumber) {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }

    public Students(char userName, char Name, char surName, char Department, int UsersCounter,int RegistrationNumber) {
        super(userName, Name, surName, Department, UsersCounter);
        registrationNumber = RegistrationNumber;
    }

    }
```

Comment: recompile, rebuild,...

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into Eclipse and it compiles.  Please save, clean, and rebuild.  Also, you may not want `public` instance variables, and the `registrationNumber` probably shouldn't be `static`.

Comment: By the way, why char and not String?

Comment: Don't set attributes visibility to public ! and use static methods to access static variable

Comment: why does half of the variable names start with upper case, it looks weird...

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase.